# MFMailComposeViewController wipes rootViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Im making sending an email available for the user with this code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
[vc setSubject:@"Test Subject"];
[vc setMessageBody:@"Test Body" isHTML:NO];
[vc setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This opens a `ViewController` with all the stuff you need to sen an email, but it completely wipes everything from the `ViewController` the user is previously on. It only removes the `subviews` because the root view is still there because the `backgroundColor` is still the same.

I have already tried `initWithRootViewController:` but it crashes.

What is happening?

Comment: Do you mean after dismiss? What is `self`?

Comment: self is the viewcontroller presenting the mailVC ofc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug... It wasn't in the code above. It seems the `viewWillDissapear:` is getting called when presenting the mailVC :/

In there I have code to remove every subview, so yeah, found the problem thanks anyways for those who answered and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "completely wipes everything". But suposing this is for iPad (and not iPhone), when presenting a view controller it goes full screen by default. If you want to change that, you have to set the `modalPresentationStyle` of the presented view controller (`MFMailComposeViewController` in your case)

Your code would look like this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
[vc setSubject:@"Test Subject"];
[vc setMessageBody:@"Test Body" isHTML:NO];
[vc setMailComposeDelegate:self];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; //You can use custom size too
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: As in completely wipes everything I mean everything disappears. Its the same color as the root view was. While the mailVC is animating you can see everything disappear and when you click cancel its all gone.

Comment: A screenshot will help.